# org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException: query did not return a unique result: 22

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, exception

1. ```
   String name="select name from table where mailid='ankita.sharma'"
   ```
2. ```
   subjectValue = subjectValue.replace("~~seekername~~", name);
   ```

   I am getting Exception on line 2, I am just replacing name that is fetching from the query that is written on line 1 ,so far I have found that query did not return a unique result: 22 exception  can come when multiple rows are getting fetched from DB(22 rows), but i have checked only single row is fetching from DB.

Comment: apparently not. That result doesn't come if there is only one result

Comment: @Stultuske ya that is the thing ,but i have checked in DB only single row is coming ,wondering what could be the other possible  reasons for this exception.

Comment: there is no "other possible reason"